# Performance implications of setting TSQL parameter length to MAX regardless of field length

Tags: sql-server-2008-r2, ado.net

I'm not currently setting my string parameter lengths in `ADO.NET`, which is causing execution plan cache pollution.

Are there any performance drawbacks to setting all string parameters to `MAX` (or some large number, like `4000`) regardless of the table field definitions?

I'm trying to avoid creating a maintenance pain in `ADO.NET` - i.e. having to mirror the DB.